# Is the calculation of $\mu_0 \cdot M$ = Tesla valid?

Tags: magnetic-fields, units

in the Paper "[Static Stern-Gerlach effect in magnetic force microscopy](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.65.032311)", they estimate:
$$\mu_0 \cdot M= 1 \text{ T}$$

with $\mu_0$ in H/m which is the permeability of the free space, and $M$ is the magnetization of a small ferromagnetic particle.

Since I want to adapt this simple calculation for my purposes **I ask myself which kind of value I shall put for $M$, or if my data sheet already gives me the value corresponding to 1 T**.

Since I am not a physicist, I had to dive deep into the topic of magnetism to get a clue what is important. It seems that the residual flux density (remanence) is
$$B_r= \mu_0 \cdot M [\text{T}]$$
which is the left magnetization at zero external field.

What I know from the data sheet of my particle is the magnetic moment of the pure material is 300 emu/cm³. The volume of the actual particle is $10^{-16}\text{cm}^3$. That gives me a magnetization with the formula 
$$M=\frac{dm}{dV}$$
of
$$M=10^{-13} \text{emu} $$

Now comes a tricky part for me, with
$$B_r= \mu_0 * M [\text{T}]$$
being 
$$B_r= 4 \pi \cdot 10^{-7} \frac{\text{H}}{\text{m}} \cdot 10^{-13} \text{emu} = ?$$

**does this give me tesla?**

I have the honest feeling that something is wrong here.

Does somebody have a clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you mixing formulas in SI with numerical values in EMU? That's basically a recipe for disaster. Where did you get the formula, and where did you get the numerical values?

Comment: Hi Emilio,
μ0⋅M=1 T is out of the Paper and
M=dm/dV from Wikipedia and the company who sold us the particle also used it.
The company gave me the value for the magnetic moment of the pure material (300 emu/cm³) and the volume of it (10^−16cm³).

Yesterday I gave it a try and calculated backwards, since I know that Br is 1T and µ0 is in H/m I ended up with M being A/m, this I can convert to cgs units which should be emu/cm³.

Is that correct that I have to add the volume magnetization for M in the formula 
Br=μ0⋅M???